# Showing that set of all vectors orthogonal to two vectors is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $A_1$, $A_2$ be vectors in $R^{n}$. Show that the set of all vectors $B$ in $R^{n}$
>   such that $B$ is perpendicular both $A^{1}$ and $A^{2}$ is a subspace.

This was one of the tasks in S.L's linear algebra text book. I've constructed such proof:

Let $W=B$.

Notice that $O^TA_1=0=O^TA_2$ (where $O$ is a null vector), thus $O$ is in W.

Suppose $B$, $C$ are orthogonal to $A_1$ and $A_2$, then:

$$A_1^{T}(B+C)=A_1^{T}B+A_1^{T}C=0=A_2^{T}(B+C)=A_2^{T}B+A_2^{T}C$$

thus it's additive linear combination which is again in $W$.

Finally, suppose there is scalar c, then $(cB) \cdot A=c(A\cdot B)=0$.

---

Hence, If I'm correct, $B$ satisfies all three axioms to be a subspace.

Does this proof have any flaws? Also isn't $B$ also a kernel (null space) of $A_{1} \cup A_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main confusion to me seems to be what is $B$? is it a vector or a subspace?

Perhaps define $$W=\{ b \in \mathbb{R}^n: A_1^Tb=A_2^Tb=0 \}$$

Also, for the closure under the addition, I would write

let $b, c \in W$, then for $i\in \{1,2\}$,

$$A_i^T(b+c)=A_i^Tb+A_i^Tc=0+0=0.$$ just to highlight that $A_i^Tb=0$ and $A_i^Tc=0$.

$W$ is the nullspace of $$\begin{bmatrix} A_1^T \\ A_2^T \end{bmatrix}$$

I do not comprehend the meaning of the union of two vectors, $A_1 \cup A_2$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Union was a mistake, I was trying to express matrix of $A^{T}_{1}$ and $A^{T}_{2}$, It seems that I was correct about null space. I'm assuming, verification of axiom for closure under addition was the only axiom that had to be modified, thus rest of axioms were proved properly without mistake, correct? Thank you again.

Comment: I think you got the main idea of what you need to prove. Just that notation is a bit confusing to me especially whether $B$ is a vector or a space.

Comment: Yes, I agree, which is one of the reasons for why I was skeptical with my proof. But your proof is much more clear, I just needed to make sure that I didn't have any other flaws rather than disorienting selection of variables.